# What does third symbol in "rw-" file mode mean?

Tags: bash, file-permissions, ls

I have trouble understanding `ls`'s manual regarding to file that has `rw-` mode. Here's the quote:

> 1. If r, the **file is readable**; if -, it is not readable.
> 2. If w, the file is writable; if -, it is not writable.
> 3. The first of the following that applies:
>
>    S     If in the owner permissions, the file is not executable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the group permissions, the file is not executable and set-group-ID mode is set.
>
>    s     If in the owner permissions, the file is executable and set-user-ID mode is set. If in the group permissions, the file is executable and setgroup-ID mode is set.
>
>    x     The file is executable or the directory is searchable.
>
>    -     The file is **neither readable**, writable, executable, nor set-user-ID nor set-group-ID mode, nor sticky.

In particular, it seem that two sections in bold contradict each other: according to the first one, since the mode begins with `r`, the file is readable, but according to the last one, the file is **not** readable. But, obviously, that is not the case.

So, what does that third section mean about file being "neither readable, writable..."?

Comment: Its the executable bit.

Comment: @ckruczek how can it be a bit, if, according to `man ls`, it can hold 4 different values?

Comment: @User112638726 any of what?

Comment: You have 4bits for describing a file permission 'drwx'. You can only manipulate the 3 permission bits and obviously not the directory bit.

Comment: @ckruczek I don't see how this answers by question. I know that files have a executable bit. However, the third symbol in this string is said to have four possible values, not two. Obviously, values `s`, `S`, `x` and `-` can't all possibly be expressed by **one bit**.

Comment: Moved question here: http://superuser.com/questions/931911/what-does-third-symbol-in-rw-file-mode-mean

Comment: Ok I think I missunderstood you question slightly :D

Comment: @MaxYankov Ignore my previous comment, after reading it again, it makes no sense so I'd just ignore it. The executable bit has no effect on whether a file is readable(at least in my experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ls` man page is not the standard.  The [POSIX standard man page for ls](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/ls/) does **not** word it in that way.  Here is the relevant extract:

> Each field shall have three character positions:
>
> 1. If 'r' , the file is readable; if '-' , the file is not readable.
> 2. If 'w' , the file is writable; if '-' , the file is not writable.
> 3. The first of the following that applies:
>
>    S
>
>      If  in <
>      *owner permissions*
>      >, the file is not executable and set-user-ID mode is set.
>              If in <
>      *group permissions*
>      >, the file is not executable and set-group-ID mode is set.
>
>    s
>
>      If in <
>      *owner permissions*
>      >, the file is executable and set-user-ID mode is  set.  If
>              in <
>      *group permissions*
>      >, the file is executable and set-group-ID mode is set.
>
>    T
>
>      If  in  <
>      *other permissions*
>      >  and  the file is a directory, search permission is not
>              granted to others, and the restricted deletion flag is set.
>
>    t
>
>      If in <
>      *other permissions*
>      > and the file is a directory, search permission is granted
>              to others, and the restricted deletion flag is set.
>
>    x
>
>      The file is executable or the directory is searchable.
>
>    -
>
>      None of the attributes of 'S' , 's' , 'T' , 't' , or 'x' applies.

Which I think makes more sense.

The type is not represented in the permissions bits – you are only looking at what `ls(1)` reports, not how it is stored. Traditionally the mode and type together use 32-bits, but that depends on the file system and on many it is now 64-bits. The permissions are only 9 bits in the inode.

See `man 2 stat` and search for `st_mode`. It is the low level C routine that `ls(1)` probably uses. On some platforms it is also available as a command-line program `man 1 stat`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was going bonkers and felt incredibly stupid trying to understand this. The manual you provided makes much more sense. My version is from OS X, by the way.

Comment: @MaxYankov:  You know I have been looking at the `ls` man page for about 35 years and never noticed that before.   I think the POSIX standard improved it, but I have not been able to find a record of that.  BTW, I'm on OS X too, and at least it says `The ls utility conforms to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001` (that's the POSIX standard).  Also check out `stat` on the command-line if you have never seen it - very powerful (also on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Each numbered point in your quote applies in turn to each of the three characters.

> If the **first** character is 'r', the file is **readable**
>
> If the **second** character is 'w', the file is **writable**
>
> If the **third** character is 'x/s/S', the file has the listed property
>
> If the character is '-', then the file does not have that property.

The first three characters (after the directory identifier) apply to **user** permissions, the second three to **group** permissions, and the third to everyone else.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "listed property"?

Comment: Also, please note that this question is about to be closed because I didn't ask it on a correct subsite; you may move your answer to super user too.